# Python: Convert numbers to words

Tags: python, dictionary, numbers, converters, words

Hello everyone I'm trying to produce a code that will convert a number to a word in a given dictionary. But it seems to not print anything at all. no errors or anything. I tried many things to find the problem, still nothing.

When I enter `6` the program kicks back nothing.

It should output `[six]`.

I thought it was a spacing problem but I dont think that is the case.

**Here's what I have**

```
import string


value = input("Enter a number 1 - 9 separted by commas: ")

def user_input(value):
    numbers = {}
    user_list = value.split(',')
    numbers = [(x.strip()) for x in user_list]
    return numbers
    print(numbers)

user_input(value)

numbers = user_input()

unit_number = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 
           5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine'}

def convert_n_to_w(numbers):
    i = len(str(numbers))

    if i == 0:
        return

    if i == 1:
        return unit_number[numbers]

    print(unit_number[numbers])
```

convert_n_to_w(numbers)

Can anyone please show me what I did doing wrong?

**Update!!!!!!!**

I added `convert_n_to_w(numbers)`  and telling me

`line 38, in <module>
    convert_n_to_w(numbers)`

`NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined`

When I thought I defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. I would like to modify you code. The code below can work well but not pythonic.

```
value = input("Enter a number 1 - 9 separted by commas: ")

def user_input(value):
    if isinstance(value, tuple):
        return list(value)
    else:
        user_list = value.split(',')
        numbers = [(x.strip()) for x in user_list]
        return numbers


unit_number = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 
           5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine'}

def convert_n_to_w(numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        print(unit_number[int(n)])

numbers = user_input(value)

convert_n_to_w(numbers)
```

Comment: Wow! Thankyou very much!!! I see now I went about it the wrong way and the problem really started in my first function.

Answer (score 3):

The print statement, `print(unit_number[numbers])`, is in the `convert_n_to_w` function. You don't call that function at any point, so the print statement is not being run.

Either call the function, or take the print statement out of the function.

Comment: changed it sorry it kick back a `name error`  I already recalled I dont know why. `convert_n_to_w(numbers)
NameError: name 'numbers' is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

```
#Dictionaries for reference
ones = {"1":"One","2":"Two","3":"Three","4":"Four","5":"Five","6":"Six", "7":"Seven","8":"Eight","9":"Nine"}
afterones = {"10":"Ten","11":"Eleven","12":"Twelve","13":"Thirteen","14":"Fourteen","15":"Fifteen","16":"Sixteen", "17":"Seventeen","18":"Eighteen","19":"Nineteen"}
tens = {"2":"Twenty","3":"Thirty","4":"Fourty","5":"Fifty","6":"Sixty", "7":"Seventy","8":"Eighty","9":"Ninety"}
grand={0:" Billion, ",1:" Million, ",2:" Thousand, ",3:""}

#Function converting number to words of 3 digit
def num_to_wrds(val):
    if val != "000":
        ans = ""
        if val[0] in ones:
            x = val
            ans = ans + ones[val[0]] + " Hundered and "
        if val[1:] in afterones:
            ans = ans + afterones[val[1:]] + " "
        elif val[1] in tens:
            ans = ans + tens[val[1]] + " "
        if val[2] in ones:
            ans = ans + ones[val[2]]
        return ans


num = input("Enter the number: ") 

# Paddiing with zeros
pad = 12-len(str(num))
numinwrds = "0"*pad + str(num)

final =""
numlis = [numinwrds[0:3],numinwrds[3:6],numinwrds[6:9],numinwrds[9:12]]

for key,grp in enumerate(numlis):

    if grp!="000":
        final = final + num_to_wrds(grp) + grand[key]

print final
```

This prints upto Values in Billions you can add more in grand dictionary it works perfect
Note: be sure to put the highest value in decreasing order

Answer (score 1):

You `return` from `user_input` before printing the numbers. The `print` statement in that function is never reached.

Update:

And as @Joni indicates you are not calling the function `convert_n_to_w` at all.

So no `print` statement is ever executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def n2w(num):
    unit_number = {0: 'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 
    5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight', 9: 'nine'}
    st=""
    while num>0 :
        a=num%10
        for i,j in unit_number.items():
            if i==a:
                st=unit_number[i]+" "+st
        num=num//10
        st=st.rstrip()
    return (st)
```